# webthread lock crash issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I can't seem to understand what's causing me this crash, it points me to no line number anywhere in the code.

[image]

Any ideas? I can't reproduce the crash constantly, causing it to be harder to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that that's the thread that's crashing?  That thread looks rather benign -- it looks like a worker thread owned by the Quartz library, and it's just waiting on a lock, which is a common operation that's unlikely to crash, unless you have random memory corruption.

Take a look at the stack traces of **all** of your threads, there might be something that jumps out more at you.  Or, to be sure that that thread is crashing, take a look at the disassembly and see which instruction caused the crash, and examine the relevant registers and memory operands in the debugger.

If that thread is in fact crashing, you almost certainly have memory corruption somewhere in your program, which is very hard to debug.  Search around for memory debugging tools, there are lots of options, but there's no silver bullet.